# On integral equivalence of forms

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, quadratic-forms

In Borevich & Shafarevich's *Number Theory*, the authors define integral equivalence of quadratic forms as follows:

> Two forms of the same degree
> with rational coefficients are called integrally equivalent if each can be obtained
> from the other by a linear change of variables with rational integer coefficients.

They further state a second definition

> In the case of forms which depend on the same
> number of variables, this is equivalent to saying that one of the forms can be
> transformed into the other by a linear change of variables with unimodular
> matrix.

But I cannot see how to prove the equivalence of the two definitions. Specifically, it seems to me that to show the first definition implies the second, one has to prove that the two linear changes in the first definition are inverse of each other, or that both changes are nonsingular. Can anyone help?

**edit:** Mr. Stucky's example in the comments has shown that the  two changes occurred in the first definition need not be invertible. But still, I think to prove that the first definition implies the second, one has to show the existence of two nonsingular changes, as is pointed out by Stucky.

Comment: I also had your intuition, but the following example has given me pause.
$$ F(x,y)=(x+y)^2 \qquad G(u,v)=(2u-v)^2. $$
There is a clear non-invertible change of variables that shows the equivalence using the first definition
$$x\mapsto 2u-v, ~~ y\mapsto 0 \qquad u\mapsto 0, ~~ v\mapsto -x-y.$$
Still, they are also equivalent under the second definition: the unimodular matrix $\begin{bmatrix}-1&3\\1&-2\end{bmatrix}$ converts $x+y$ to $2u-v$ and hence $F$ to $G$.

Comment: There's something here like "The change of variables don't have to be invertible per se, they only have to surject onto the 'relevant' subspaces," but I haven't been able to work it out. For instance, if form is quadratic and nondegenerate, then invertibility on the nose is required.

Comment: @EricNathanStucky I guess the two singular changes could be modified to get two invertible changes?